# How to override the onDraw() function in Component for Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I can't find the `onDraw()` method in Component. Can someone explain to me how to override the onDraw method for Component in Harmony OS?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to implement **[Component.DrawTask](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/component_drawtask-0000001054678675)** to your custom Component, Then you will be able to override **onDraw()** and perform custom Drawing operations. For Example,

```java
 public class CustomComponent extends Component implements Component.DrawTask {
 
  public CustomComponent(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // DrawTask
        addDrawTask(this::onDraw);
    }
    
     @Override
    public void onDraw(Component component, Canvas canvas) {
        ...
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `Component.DrawTask` interface, and execute the draw task using the `onDraw` method. You can use the `Canvas` provided by this method to accurately control the appearance of UI elements. Before executing a draw task, you need to define a `Paint`.

The sample code is as follows:

```
public class CustomComponent extends Component implements Component.DrawTask,Component.EstimateSizeListener {
    // Circle width
    private static final float CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH = 100f;

    // Paint for drawing the circle 
    private Paint circlePaint;    
    
    public CustomComponent(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Initialize the Paint.
        initPaint();

        // Add a draw task.
        addDrawTask(this);
    }

    private void initPaint(){
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE_STYLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Component component, Canvas canvas) {

        // Draw a circle whose center coordinate is (500,500) and radius is 400.
        canvas.drawCircle(500,500,400,circlePaint);
    }

    ...
}
```

For details about the override `onDraw()` method in Harmony OS, pls kindly refer to  the [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-custom-components-0000001139369661).